# c:set variable not printing

Tags: mysql

I want to use this RecipeSelected variable value to use for c:set variable and print? But it is not printing anything.

```
<%;
     String RecipeSelected = (String)session.getAttribute("Recipe");
     out.println("this is getAttribute from servlet "+RecipeSelected );%>
     <c:set var="id" value="${RecipeSelected }"/>
<%  out.println("using c:out id is : " );%>
<c:out value = '${id}'/>
```

Comment: Your code is not an sql code. So the question tag is inappropriate.

Comment: Change your tags, and also your question should be a summary of the issue. Move the "I want to ..." stuff into the question body and provide a summary that easily synthesises the core issue for a reader.